# Jquery calculate discount from select values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm showing live calculated price from select box and multiplying the amount through another select box like so:

```
$('#tour_type').change(function(){
$('#price').val($("#tour_type option:selected").val());
});
```

**My selects:**

```
<option selected="" value="">Select a Tour</option>
<option value="3900">3 Hour Tour</option>
<option value="5900">Full Day Tour</option>
<option value="11800">2 Day Tour</option>
```

**Value multiplied with:**

```
<option selected="" value="">Select Riders</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
```

What I'm trying to do is based on the amount of riders (select 2) reduce some of the values from select 1

**For example:**

3 Hour Tour selected |  1-3 Riders value is 3900 | 4-6 Riders value is 3400 | etc.

Full day tour selected |  1-3 Riders value is 5900 | 4-6 Riders value is 5100 | etc.

How do I change the values of select1 based on value from select2 ?

Through given answers I tried this:

```
$("#riders").change(function(){

    if($("#riders").val()=="1" || $("#riders").val()=="2" || $("#riders").val()=="3")
    {
   $('#tourtype option:content("3 Hour Tour")').attr('value', '1000');
   $('#tourtype option:content("Full Day Tour")').attr('value', '2000');
   $('#tourtype option:content("2 Day Tour")').attr('value', '3000');
    }
  else if($("#riders").val()=="4" || $("#riders").val()=="5" || $("#riders").val()=="6")
    {
   $('#tourtype option:content("3 Hour Tour")').attr('value', '4000');
   $('#tourtype option:content("Full Day Tour")').attr('value', '5000');
   $('#tourtype option:content("2 Day Tour")').attr('value', '6000');
    }
    });

<select name="tourtype" id="tourtype">
  <option value="3900">3 Hour Tour</option>
  <option value="5900">Full Day Tour</option>
  <option value="11800">2 Day Tour</option>
</select>

<select name="riders" id="riders">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
</select>
```

But that doesn't work, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: So what is your question ?

Comment: How to change values of select1 based on rider numbers of select 2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
       $(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#riders').on("change", function()
    {
    alert("hie");
       if($("#riders").val()=="1" || $("#riders").val()=="2" || $("#riders").val()=="3")

    {
    $("#tourtype option").each(function() {
    if($(this).text()=="3 Hour Tour")
    {
    $(this).attr('value', '1000');
    }
    else if($(this).text()=="Full Day Tour")
    {
    $(this).attr('value', '2000');
    }

    else
    {
    $(this).attr('value', '3000');
    }
    console.log($(this).text());
});

    }
    else if($("#riders").val()=="4" || $("#riders").val()=="5" || $("#riders").val()=="6")
    {
    $("#tourtype option").each(function() {
    if($(this).text()=="3 Hour Tour")
    {
    $(this).attr('value', '4000');
    }
    else if($(this).text()=="Full Day Tour")
    {
    $(this).attr('value', '5000');
    }

    else
    {
    $(this).attr('value', '6000');
    }
    console.log($(this).text());
});
    }
    else
    {
    alert("hie3");
   $("#tourtype option").each(function() {
    if($(this).text()=="3 Hour Tour")
    {
    $(this).attr('value', '7000');
    }
    else if($(this).text()=="Full Day Tour")
    {
    $(this).attr('value', '8000');
    }

    else
    {
    $(this).attr('value', '9000');
    }
    console.log($(this).text());
});
    }
    });
});
```

Comment: That looks like what I want, I've added that to my initial question, it doesn't seem to work for me, any idea ?

Comment: Ok looks like the problem is: `unsupported pseudo: content`

Answer (score 1):

Use switch statement based on Riders number.

```
function calculateDiscount() {
  switch ($(RIDERS_SELECT).val()) {
    case 1: 
    case 2: 
    case 3: 
      return 500;
    case 4: 
    case 5: 
    case 6: 
      return 800;
    // etc. 
  }
}
```